# Fetch VMWare cluster level metrics

Tags: vmware, metrics

I am trying to fetch the cluster level metrics of vmware, and I'm doing so by iterating over the hosts and summing the overall usage metrics. However, there seems to be a mismatch between the obtained result and the output as visible on vsphere client.

Comment: Do you have any examples?